# Typoscript Breadcrumb - special.range parameter

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm struggling with a simple Breadcrumb Navigation in Typoscript. I just want a simple link to the higher-level page. So if you're on page-3 there should be a link to page-2, if on page-4 there should be a link to page-4 and so on.

I've already been testing different `special.range` parameters. None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs:

> If the value is < 0, entryLevel is chosen from "behind" in the rootLine. Thus "-1" is a menu with items from the outermost level, "-2" is the level before the outermost...

In ***rootline*** menu that means the `-1` level is current page, `-2` one level above current, etc. so linking only parent level is as simple as:

```
lib.linkOneLevelAbove = HMENU
lib.linkOneLevelAbove {
  special = rootline
  special.range = -2|-2
  1 = TMENU
  1.NO = 1
}

page.1 < lib.linkOneLevelAbove
```